# What would be more appropriate for my need (XML\Json) and how do I use it?

Tags: c#, json, xml

I'm making a game, in C# (MonoGame if it makes a difference), and the game has both a server and a client.
I want the client to hold some kind of textual representation of the items, so that when I load the client it will read the file and parse it into game objects so that I can easily handle items.

I thought about using XML or JSON, I know the basics of both, but I really don't know
How to use them in code.

What do you think would be more appropriate? I think XML is more appropriate but I might be wrong, this is why I'm asking...

The file would have this kind of structure

```
<items>
  <item>
    <id></id>
    <name></name>
    <cost></cost>
    <description></description>
    <pathofimage></pathofimage>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id></id>
    <name></name>
    <cost></cost>
    <description></description>
    <pathofimage></pathofimage>
  </item>
</items>
```

How, given this example structure, do I get the data from the file?

Comment: As a coincidence(?)  the related questions list at the right side of the screen show some nice starting points.

Comment: Consider the payload. If there is going to be communication between server and client, JSON (due to it's notation) is going to be more lightweight. For large amounts of data, that could matter.

Comment: I'm still considering what to do about it, because I think that eventually, I'll have an ItemPool implementation the differs in server and client (server has all logics, client only needs to have visuals), so eventually I think that the communication regarding the items would be to transfer the ID of the item, which would be synced manually by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, XML is easier to work with using builtin .NET namespaces like System.Xml or System.Xml.Linq.

JSON could be better if you'll use this data in javascript or in some public game API, but it will need some third-party library to work with it like JSON.NET (it gives better json support). Also json is more lightweight then xml and large amount of data will be smaller in json.

parsing code example using linq for xml (System.Xml.Linq namespace):

```
var xmlString = @"<items>
  <item>
    <id>100</id>
    <name>lance</name>
    <cost>9.99</cost>
    <description></description>
    <pathofimage></pathofimage>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>101</id>
    <name>sword</name>
    <cost>12.50</cost>
    <description></description>
    <pathofimage></pathofimage>
  </item>
</items>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var items = doc.Root.Elements("item").Select(e => new {
                                    Id = int.Parse(e.Element("id").Value), 
                                    Name = e.Element("name").Value, 
                                    Cost = decimal.Parse(e.Element("cost").Value)});
```

results:

[image: results]

(I'm using LinqPad for represent results here, highly recommend it for playing with linq and linq for xml)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the explanation! I'm trying something right now, i'll be sure to check your method as well.  
Just for clearance, I can simply read the text of a file with a filestream and do the same, right?

Comment: Welcome! Yes, sure you could read file into the string and use it the same way

Comment: or you could use XDocument.Load method and use file name or stream

Comment: var xml = XDocument.Load("itemsdoc.xml");

            var items = xml.Root.Elements("item").
                Select(e => new Item()
                {
                    ID = int.Parse(e.Element("id").Value),
                    Name = e.Element("name").Value,
                    Cost = int.Parse(e.Element("cost").Value),
                    Description = e.Element("description").Value,
                    Asset = e.Element("path").Value
                });

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Debug.Print(item.ToString());
            }

Comment: It gives a NullReferenceException. In debug, I go through the Select method, it tries to do the `in items` and throws, marking the `new Item()...`

Comment: nvm, bug fixed - had a type: `e.Element("path")` instead of `e.Element("asset")`